# Laravel 5.7 what is the Resource Controller route names using some namespaces?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-artisan

After upgrade to Laravel 5.7,
I was using using route:resource for CRUD in Admin 
And the namespace is Admin.
So for example UsersController, the route name for create is

```
route('admin.users.create')
```

But It doesn't work for me in Laravel 5.7.
Also I can't use the command

```
php artisan route:list
```

because it display an error in connection, although I use a proper connection params in .env file.

Comment: remove unnecessary routes or wrong route and then run `php artisan route:list
`

Comment: can you show the error for the route:list?

Comment: Are you using vagrant box or something which has your project and also mysql connection and are you firing artisan commands on your local terminal(not after doing vagrant ssh)?

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces don't alter route names; they only define a namespace within which the app will search for a controller.

You can add route name prefix `->name('admin.')` to your `admin` route group.

Answer (score 0):

Assign name in routes->web.php:  `name('admin.users.create');`like that.

`Route::get('/user', 'UserController@create')->name('admin.users.create');`

Then use it in your controller ,view or model

`route('admin.users.create')`.